# AWS Polly results format MPEG

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I am trying to use AWS Polly for text to speech functionality of my simple JAVA console application. 
I get result from AWS but once I try to play it with AudioStreamPlayer (class can be found here: http://blog.conygre.com/2016/12/06/at-the-third-stroke-the-time-will-be-spoken-by-aws-polly/) I get an error.

Seems that format of result I get from AWS is MPEG and not MP3 as requested.

My Code:

```
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(key, secret);
    System.out.println(System.getenv("AWS_REGION"));
    AmazonPollyClient apClient = (AmazonPollyClient) AmazonPollyClientBuilder.standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
    .build();
    SynthesizeSpeechRequest tssRequest = new SynthesizeSpeechRequest();
    tssRequest.setText("Hello World");
    tssRequest.setVoiceId("Ruben");
    tssRequest.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mp3);
    SynthesizeSpeechResult tssResult = apClient.synthesizeSpeech(tssRequest);
    System.out.println(tssResult.getContentType());
    InputStream in = tssResult.getAudioStream();
    BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(in);
    AudioStreamPlayer player = new AudioStreamPlayer(); 
            player.play(bin);
```

Console Output:

```
eu-west-1
audio/mpeg
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream
    at AudioStreamPlayer.play(AudioStreamPlayer.java:35)
    at PollyTest.main(PollyTest.java:31)
Caused by: javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1121)
    at AudioStreamPlayer.play(AudioStreamPlayer.java:16)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: mp3 is not supported in java try PCM